# Multiple references in LaTeX

Tags: citing, ieeetran

I'm writing a paper and using the `IEEEtran.cls` in LaTeX. I need to have my references to appear like:

```
\cite{test1,test2,test3}
```

I want :

```
[1-3]
```

I searched and found that I need to include cite package. However, after I have used cite packages, I get :

```
[1]-[3]
```

How can I get [1-3] instead of [1]-[3]? without using new commands ?

Here is an example of what I have :

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{cite}
 \begin{document}
 \section{Test}
 \cite{test1,test2,test3}. 
 \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
 \bibliography{test}
 \end{document}
```

the test.bib file:

```
@MISC{test1,
title = {Reference test1}
}
@MISC{test2,
title = {Reference test2}
}
@MISC{test3,
title = {Reference test3}
}
```

output :

```
       I. TEST
   [1]–[3].
       REFERENCES
  [1] “Reference test1.”
  [2] “Reference test2.”
  [3] “Reference test3.”
```

Comment: ...`get [1]-[3] instead of [1]-[3]`? What's the difference?

Comment: sorry, i mean [1-3] instead of [1]-[3].

Comment: @ nneonneo ,check the update!!

Comment: @vonbrand . I guess that's why I'm asking ? the real output is different from the expected output. I'm 100% sure that I'm getting [1]-[3] instead of [1-3] ?

Comment: I use IEEEtran and in no way does it behave like you say.. If you want help, you'll need to give a minimal example (one I can copy completely into my latex and compile) where the problem occurs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. The IEEE 'house style' is to use '[1]-[3]' rather than '[1-3]', so with `IEEEtran` the output is deliberate. Could you explain a bit more about your document so we can understand what the aim is?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I wouldn't use the conference mode of IEEE but use `ieeeconf` directly instead if I were you but that's another story.

IEEE has certain standards and all their classes, not surprisingly, obey those standards. What you are asking is something IEEE doesn't want and that's why it's not supported. However for personal use you can override it. Using `natbib` is not a good idea with IEEE as it's specifically discouraged.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@MISC{test1,
title = {Reference test1}
}
@MISC{test2,
title = {Reference test2}
}
@MISC{test3,
title = {Reference test3}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}    

\begin{document}

 \section{Test}
 \cite{test1,test2,test3}.
 \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
 \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it works. Regarding your suggestion to use ieeeconf. I tried to use it directly(\documentclass{ieeeconf}), got an error? Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Eng.Mohd You can simply look at your conference website for the class file. Usually each IEEE community, places one style file for the author kit and place it in your document directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, this what I found on the website. It's IEEEtran where you provide the mode[conference].

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
```

instead of `\usepackage{cite}` .

Comment: You may also want to provide the option `numbers`. This tells `natbib` that it's dealing with a numeric rather than an author-year citation style.

Comment: Jan and Mico. Thank you . But I would like to make it with \cite.                                                        @NathanG check the example that I provide to make you believe!

Comment: I much prefer `natbib`, but unfortunately find myself in positions where `cite` is required, like with the template for the *PLOS One* journal.

Comment: You really need:
\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}    
\renewcommand{\citepunct}{,}