# BibTeX, IEEEtran and multiple citations

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I have encountered a problem when doing multiple citations using BibTeX and the document class `IEEEtran` in Mac OS X (Version 10.6.8). The desired effect is similar to this:

> References [1, 2, 3].

with *thin* spaces in-between. Instead, I get

> References [1], [2], [3].

For more details, see the attached example code. I tried the package `cite` and it didn't solve the problem. In fact, using `cite` (without options) produces this

> References [1]-[3]

which is not what I want (I don't want compressed citations, which is a different thing, so this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98595/multiple-references-in-latex)). The `[nocompress]` option of `cite` doesn't help either.

This is the example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, draftclsnofoot, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
References~\cite{ref1, ref2, ref3}.
\bibliography{mybiblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

And this is the `mybiblio.bib` file:

```
@article{ref1,
    Author = {Surname1, N. and Surname2, N. and Surname3, N.},
    Journal = {Test},
    Number = 0,
    Pages = {1-2},
    Title = {Reference title},
    Volume = 0,
    Year = 2016
    }

@article{ref2,
    Author = {Surname1, N. and Surname2, N.},
    Journal = {Test},
    Number = 0,
    Pages = {1-2},
    Title = {Reference2 title},
    Volume = 0,
    Year = 2016
    }
    
@article{ref3,
    Author = {Surname1, N.},
    Journal = {Test},
    Number = 0,
    Pages = {1-2},
    Title = {Reference3 title},
    Volume = 0,
    Year = 2016
    }
```

P.S. I can't use the `natbib` package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`IEEEtran`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) explicitly defines citations to be separated into distinct `[1],[2],[3]` rather than the default `[1,2,3]` when the [`cite`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package is used by the `\def\citepunct{], [}` command which is used by [`cite`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite).  To over-rule this you can just use `\def\citepunct{,}` to produce `[1,2,3]` or insert a manual space, i.e. for a small spacing `\,` after the comma `\def\citepunt{,\,}` produces the following.

[image]

Produced from

```
\documentclass[12pt, draftclsnofoot, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybiblio.bib}
@article{ref1,
    Author = {Surname1, N. and Surname2, N. and Surname3, N.},
    Journal = {Test},
    Number = 0,
    Pages = {1-2},
    Title = {Reference title},
    Volume = 0,
    Year = 2016
    }

@article{ref2,
    Author = {Surname1, N. and Surname2, N.},
    Journal = {Test},
    Number = 0,
    Pages = {1-2},
    Title = {Reference2 title},
    Volume = 0,
    Year = 2016
    }

@article{ref3,
    Author = {Surname1, N.},
    Journal = {Test},
    Number = 0,
    Pages = {1-2},
    Title = {Reference3 title},
    Volume = 0,
    Year = 2016
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}

\def\citepunct{,\,}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
References~\cite{ref1, ref2, ref3}.
\bibliography{mybiblio}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

It may be worth noting that [`IEEEtran`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) does the same for the compressed citation by defaulting to `\def\citedash{]--[}` producing `[1]--[3]` rather than `[1--3]` which may be the expected result.

Comment: Of course it should probably be noted that `IEEEtran` do this to make references appear as the IEEE want, so if this is for submission to a journal any such changes will likely be futile.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Reading your comment I understood that IEEE (when you are using the IEEETran template) wants you to have the references as [1],[2],[3],[4] rather than [1]-[4]. Is that correct? Therefore, is it advised to leave the template as it is?

Comment: @kalmanIsAGameChanger yes, the default style of `IEEEtran` is as intended even if it looks odd.