# How to cite as superscripts in the text IN FRONT OF THE punctuation mark using `BibTeX` with `unsrt` style?

Tags: citing, cite-package, multiple-citations

I want to get superscript-positioned citations in my text in front of the ".?!" at the end of a sentence. So far it appears always behind the end of the sentence: `blabla. [1,2]` Can someone tell my how to fix that?

Also is there a way to have in the output bibliography the `[1]` numbers without superscript and the last name of the author first?

Here's my example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,margin=25mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}
\usepackage{url,hyperref}

\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\tt}
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@citess}[1]{\textsuperscript{\,[#1]}} \makeatother

\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{One}
 Within the troughs \cite{spencer2013} and blabla \cite{porco2006,spencer2013}.

\newpage 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of my output:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple references in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98595/multiple-references-in-latex)

Comment: Your MWE does not result in the output you describe. I get “blablabla. [?,?]”, so although the citation is moved behind the full stop, both references are put together with a comma. At least, combining two citations in one `\cite` macro is working in your MWE.

Comment: Ok now I got the same output as you but how can I move them in front of the punctuation mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the movement of punctuation marks with the `nomove` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel,nomove]{cite}
\usepackage{url,hyperref}

\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\small\tt}
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@citess}[1]{\textsuperscript{\,[#1]}} \makeatother

\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{One}
 Within the troughs \cite{spencer2013} and blabla \cite{porco2006,spencer2013}.

\newpage 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```